Suddenly /etc/fstab user options are ignored for my ntfs partition
I have had my documents on a separate partition, so that I can access it from other os, using NTFS. It has worked fairly well until yesterday when I upgraded to ubuntu 24. I wonder if the spec for /etc/fstab has changed for NTFS partitions.
Mount is ignoring all the following options:
user_id=1000
group_id=1000
uid=1000
user
users

which had worked for version 22 LTS. Now my disk is mounted for root only, and it becomes write-protected.
There are lots of questions and answers regarding this, but none work, it seems that ubuntu is ignoring all the user related options on /etc/fstab. The numeric representation of my user and group are still 1000
How can I fix it? what am I missing?
Btw, I am not allowed to chown the drive either, it's working as a read-only drive. So, I don't even have a workaround
@david I don't know the answer to your question, but here the relevant fstab entry:
UUID=040F72B75A4D2939                       /home/joaquin/Documents   auto   nofail,nls=iso8859-1,permissions,auto,exec,uid=1000,user_id=1000,group_id=1000,umask=000,users   0 0

It has a lot of dumb options because I've been trying to brute force some functioning working parameter. Disk is write protected from both Nautilus and Dolphin.

thanks @graham, making the change

Does the relevant partition mount through Files (Nautilus) OtherLocation->YourDataDisk? Can you append to your question the relevant mount from your fstab.

@david I added the info :)

Is the other OS WIN8/10? Is it using fast boot? If so it can leave the disk in a non-mountable state. AT YOU OWN RISK you could run the following 'sudo ntfsfix /dev/sdXY' but you will first need to identify the correct NTFS partition using 'fdisk -l'  & subsiture X Y.  'ntfsfix'  is a utility that fixes some common NTFS problems.  ntfsfix is NOT a Linux version of chkdsk.  It only repairs some  fundamental  NTFS inconsistencies,  resets  the  NTFS  journal file and schedules an NTFS consistency check for the first boot into Windows.

nope, the disk is not used for mount or anything. I've disabled fast boot too.
I will try boot to windows nevertheless see if anything changes

I figured what had happened to the partition: thanks to @david's suggestion, ntfsfix mentioned some cache being open by windows. I figured maybe windows os left the partition in some unusual state, maybe due to an unexpected shutdown or something I didn't notice. Rebooting to windows, making sure the partition was ok, and booting back, solved the problem.
Thanks for all the help in the comments!
